# I am trying to run NGINX on 8080, the server is not showing the index page. But 80 its working

Tags: nginx, centos7, web-hosting

I am trying to run NGINX on 8080, the server is not showing the index page. But 80 its working. I did a sudo nginx -s reload but getting no response on my browser. trying to access the using https://http://192.168.8.104:8081/ What could be mistake?

Here is  /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf page

```
server {
 listen 8081 default_server;
 server_name www.hello.com;
 location / {
 root /usr/share/nginx/html;
 # alias /usr/share/nginx/html;
 index index.html index.htm;
 }
}
```

Comment: Did you open port 8081 in the firewall? Is SELinux running?

Comment: Thanks! I will have to check this. I opened the firewall port   

sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8081/tcp --permanent sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8081/tcp --permanent 

@Sven

Comment: Reloaded NGINX using nginx -s reload but still its showing as no response.

Comment: Thanks its working! I had to disable SELinux  Used this https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-disable-selinux-on-centos-7/

Answer (score 1):

So if you're running SeLinux on your maschine, you can simple add this port to "http_port_t". With this command you can check if the port is allowed as webserver port

```
[root@zora nginx]# semanage port -l | grep http_port_t
http_port_t                    tcp      80, 81, 443, 488, 8008, 8009, 8443, 9000
pegasus_http_port_t            tcp      5988
[root@zora nginx]#
```

With the command "semanage" you can add new ports e.g. 8080 to "http_port_t", after adding this port, you must reload your nginx.

```
[root@zora nginx]# semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 8080
```